# Change URL using .htaccess - duplicate content

Tags: php, .htaccess, concrete5

I've trying to alter a URL which is automatically generated when using a page block in concrete 5 from a blog. The reason for doing this is because its getting picked up for duplicate content in moz.

the URL in question is blog?ccm_paging_p_b4641=3 with the number 3 incrementing each time the user goes to the next page. Im aiming to achieve a smarter url without all the spam that is above.

Ive tried this without any luck:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^blog/([^/.]+)/?$ blog?ccm_paging_p_b4641=$1 [L]
```

Any help will be appreciated,

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a new redirect URL to redirect old URL to new pretty one:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+blog/?\?ccm_paging_p_b4641=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /blog/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^blog/([^/.]+)/?$ blog?ccm_paging_p_b4641=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```